# how to find the variable that is holding given address from corefile

Tags: gdb, coredump

I am debugging memory corruption issue, I have the core file and know the address that is getting corrupted. This address is not supposed to be written by any code after initialization but some code is corrupting it.
When I grep the core file, I see that some references(possible culprits) pointing to this.
Now I need to reverse map from culprit address to source code, any idea how to find the variable name given the address using GDB from the corefile?
Issue not reproducible hence this is the only lead I have.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Please support it with code or pseudo code to make it easier to understand. I believe including any error messages would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to reverse map from culprit address to source code

Not all addresses map to source code. Global and static variable addresses can be mapped to source, but heap and stack addresses can not.

> any idea how to find the variable name given the address using GDB from the corefile?

For global or static addresses, do this:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x12341234
```